# How to read information from a certain line in C?

Tags: c

I have a `results.txt` file and on the seventh line I have numbers in form like:

```
3 5 6 1 9 7 4
```

I want to gather information how many of them `> 5` and how many of them `< 5`.

How can I do this process for all of them?

By the way, the seventh line is the last line of the file.

Comment: Please post your code (even if it is incomplete). This will make it clear in which aspect you need help.

Comment: I have no pre-codes for that. Just    
 FILE *input;
    input=fopen("input.txt","r");

Comment: Look at the questions in the related list for similar problems; your needs are probably met by some of those.  Do you want the seventh line (in the case where there might be several hundred lines in the file), or do you want the last line in the file (which happens to be the seventh in your small data set).  Is the mention of 7 accidental or material to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just read one line at a time and count.  When you reach 7, that's your seventh line.  Use `fgets`.  Once you have the line you can use `strtol` in a loop to read each value as an integer.

Reference: [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)

Answer (score 1):

To skip 1 line in the input file:

```
fscanf(f, "%*[^\n]\n");
```

To read 1 number from the file:

```
int number;
fscanf(f, "%d", &number);
```

To compare a number with 5:

```
if (number < 5)
{
    ...
}
```

P.S. The site http://www.cplusplus.com has some examples for the basic stuff you need. That site is dedicated to C++ but at your level there so little difference between C and C++, you can use the examples for your work (if you understand them).

Example: [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf) (at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_MAX 1024

int main() {
    int line_count = 7;
    int fd = open('file', r);
    int smaller_than_five = 0, bigger_than_five = 0;
    int number;

    while (line_count != 0) {
        fgets(input_line, LINE_MAX, fd);
        line_count--;
    }
    while(sscanf(input_line, "%d", &number) != EOF) {
        if (number > 5) bigger_than_five++;
        else if (number < 5) smaller_than_five++;
    }

    /*
     * Now you have:
     *  smaller_than_five which is the count of numbers smaller than five
     *  bigger_than_five which is the count of numbers bigger than five
     */
     return 0;
}
```

This works when the numbers are on seventh line. If they are on the last (but could be second or 51st), you'll have to change the first `while` to read while you have not reached the end.